# Removing item from arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make an AlertDialog that gives you the option to delete the item you clicked in a Listview. I get the AlertDialog with the 2 options, but when i click them the AlertDialog just closes and nothing happends.
Code below, thanks ahead.
Also when i press the positive button (that should delete the item) and i press the item again the app crashes.

```
private void registerClickCallBack() {
    ListNote = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    ListNote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paret, View viewClicked, final int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Notitie verwijderen?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            lv.remove(position);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Nee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv);
            ListNote.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}`
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? Does this line is reached? `lv.remove(position);`

Comment: What is `lv` in `lv.remove(position)`?

Comment: @Zakir lv is the name of the arralist. Didnt think of adding the part where i made the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. I forgot to edit the listview inside the onclick method. so the arraylist was empty but the value was still in the listview. I moved the arrayadapter and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you are looking for arrayList.RemoveAt(index)

You are attempting to arrayList.Remove(Object)

The object you are attempting to remove is an int named 'position' and it does not exist in your arrayList (lv) so won't throw an exception.

There is a difference between Removing an object At a specific index and removing a specific object. Depends on the reference you are passing.

edit: attempting clarification

Comment: Are you sure `removeAt`? See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)), `RemoveAt` you are using C# in android?

Comment: I had a working code without the alertdialog. In this code i used the lv.remove(position) as well, and it worked. So i dont think that could be the problem